# python: X25519 is not supported by this version of OpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl

I try to exec python app (yowsup) register request and get error:

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py", line 42, in generate
    _Reasons.UNSUPPORTED_EXCHANGE_ALGORITHM
cryptography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm: X25519 is not supported by this version of OpenSSL.
```

i get latest version openssl:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1b.tar.gz
```

unarchive it and configure:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib
```

then:

```
make && make test && make install
```

fixed links in os and cheked version:

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
built on: Sat Apr 27 14:42:16 2019 UTC
platform: linux-armv4
options:  bn(64,32) rc4(char) des(long) idea(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread  -march=armv7-a -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DZLIB -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

after it i get latest pythone 2.7 and recompile it for using system openssl:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/lib/"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl"
$ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/custom/python/ --enable-optimizations
make && make install
```

fixed links then try:

```
root@orangepiplus2e:~# python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

then check using open ssl by python:

```
root@orangepiplus2e:~# python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
```

but it still not works, my OS:

```
root@orangepiplus2e:/etc/ld.so.conf.d# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```